# Migration dependencies reference nonexistent When starting a new project

Tags: python, django, database, migration

Hi Guys sorry for being so dumb, but i got this problem even after installing django again and starting a new project, have searched online with no avail for a week now.

Every time i run migrations this error appears, it is giving me a headache, have tried, python manage.py runserver --fake, have tried removing py files deleting database and so on and failed

Here is the error

```
PS C:\Users\Willie\desktop\maoni\maoni> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", lin
e 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", lin
e 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migr
ate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", l
ine 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", lin
e 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", lin
e 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", lin
e 244, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line
 261, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line
 261, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line
 104, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0009_user_following dependencies reference nonexistent
 parent node ('account', '0001_initial')
PS C:\Users\Willie\desktop\maoni\maoni> python 825 manage.py migrate
C:\Users\Willie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe: can't open file '825': [Errno 2] No such file or d
irectory
```

[image: my screenshort]

Comment: The last lines are important but are cut off. It would be better if you did a copy-paste instead to post a picture.

Comment: Thanks Attersson, have copy pasted the code

Comment: Apparently there is no `0001_initial` migration in your `account` app.

Comment: Yes there is no, but i had another app with the account app, and i deleted it